# Need to input variable number of variables in TI-nspire CX CAS

Tags: ti-basic

I want to write a TIBasic program for the nspire CS CAS which will perform simple finite element analysis. In order to do this, I need to be able to input a non-specific number of variables since the number of members in a problem will vary.

Is there a command or trick I can use to program variables k1,k2,k3,...,kn?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to use multiple variables like that. You might be able to use a [list](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/sk:lists) and store all your variables there. Lists can only hold up to 999 elements though, so that'll limit what you can do.